# Change currency symbol format

Tags: magento, currency-formatting

We have created two websites for two different regions. On website with ID 2, we have USD as our currency and product price is shown as US$50. But we want to show it as $50(USD). Is there any way to do so?
We are using Magento 1.5 currently and also planning to upgrade it to 1.7 soon.

Comment: what locale are you using?

Answer (score 4):

you have to edit the xml corresponding to the locale of your store, e.g. if you're using english of USA, the file you are looking for is MAGENTO_ROOT/lib/Zend/Locale/Data/en_US.xml. In it you add (before the `</ldml>` ending tag):

```
<numbers>
    <currencyFormats>
        <currencyFormatLength>
            <currencyFormat>
                <pattern>¤#,##0.00(USD);(¤#,##0.00(USD))</pattern>
            </currencyFormat>
        </currencyFormatLength>
        <unitPattern count="one">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
        <unitPattern count="other">{0} {1}</unitPattern>
    </currencyFormats>
</numbers>
```

After that, you have to manually delete the content of MAGENTO_ROOT/var/cache/

Comment: If there a way of changing it programmaticaly ?

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't clear, Do you know a way of doing it programmacticaly ?